# weird colors showing up that aren't on my stylesheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add a table in a page, and I can't get my server to show very many changes and it decided that my background colors are black and gray.  I removed every color from the index and the style sheet, and it's still a black background for my first div and when a link is clicked, all of my text is unreadable because it's covered by this charcoal color.  I've wasted hours on this still have no idea why my div's and images won't size and my background colors aren't changing.

HTML is

```
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <link href="http://localhost/stylesheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="http://localhost/mary/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <!DOCTYPE><HTML>
    <head>
        <title>Mary Bishop</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/jscript.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>
<div id="content">
    <div id="list">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
        <li style="font-family:Andale Mono"><a href="#">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
        <li style="font-family:fantasy"><a href="#">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
        <li style="font-family: Bitstream Vera Sans Mono"><a href="#">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div> 
</div>


    <div id="background">
            <div class="col1">stuff1            
            </div>
            <div class="col1">stuff2  
            </div>  
            <div class="col1">stuff3
            </div>
            <br />
            <br />
            <div class="col2">
                <ol>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                </ol>   
            </div>
            <div class="col2">
                <ol>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                    <li>item</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <div class="col2">more stuff</div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS is

```
#content {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

body{
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#list{
    height:1600px;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#list ul, #list li{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#list a{
    position:absolute;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#list a:hover{

}

#background {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}

.col1 {
    display: inline;
    z-index:2;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}

.col2{
    display: inline;
    z-index: 3;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

(you can see, I even took out the hover color for the links, and it's still there!)

JQuery is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var element = $('#list a');
    var offset = 0;
    var stepping = 0.03;
    var list = $('#list');
    var $list = $(list);
        $list.mousemove(function (e) {
            var topOfList = $list.eq(0).offset().top;
            var listHeight = $list.height();
            stepping = (e.clientY - topOfList) / listHeight * 0.2 - 0.1;
});
for (var i = element.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    element[i].elemAngle = i * Math.PI * 2 / element.length;
        }
    setInterval(render, 30);
function render() {
    for (var i = element.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var angle = element[i].elemAngle + offset;
            x = 120 + Math.sin(angle) * 10;
            y = 45 + Math.cos(angle) * 40;
            size = Math.round(40 - Math.sin(angle) * 20);
                var elementCenter = $(element[i]).width() / 2;
                var leftValue = (($list.width() / 2) * x / 100 - elementCenter) + "px"
                    $(element[i]).css("fontSize", size + "pt");
                    $(element[i]).css("opacity", size / 100);
                    $(element[i]).css("zIndex", size);
                    $(element[i]).css("left", leftValue);
                    $(element[i]).css("top", y + "%");
                }
                offset += stepping;
            }
});

$(function(){
    $('#list').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $('#background').show("explode", 500);
        });
});
```

I ran it through JSFiddle, and I get the same thing, so I know it's not my server, it's my code :(  Please help, I am beyond my wits end with this one.  Frustration doesn't even begin to describe what I'm feeling right now.  :(

Comment: Can you link us the jsfiddle?

Comment: why do you have meta and link tags above the DOCTYPE? I created a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jsbrown1/JFJH9/)

Comment: First,place the meta and the link tags in the head section of your HTML and the script tag before the closing the body tag.

Comment: sorry, I think i did a skip over when I copied and it transposed some lines.  It's the doctype first and the meta and script tags are in the head section

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m39je/

Comment: This won't help very much, but when this happens to me (as it often does) I strip everything down to HTML only, then add back CSS class/id by class/id. Then lastly add the js line by line.

Comment: thanks, Tim.  I may just have to do that.

Comment: I dont think I can reproduce the problem... I open up the js fiddle link (in Chrome) and see no odd colors. Background is white, text is black, links are blue. Might it be some setting on your browser or OS?

Comment: I'm using chrome, too.  That's odd :(

Comment: any idea which settings it could be?

Comment: You have two external stylesheets, which aren't linked in the jsfiddle. I'm guessing you didn't go through the jquery-ui css sheet and remove all colors.

Comment: @Mary so you do have the problem in the jsfiddle you showed? Can you do a screenshot, so we'll know what we're looking for?

Comment: both stylesheets are linked in js fiddle.  CSS is one, javscript is the other

Comment: i took a screen shot, just not sure how to get it to show up here.  Anyone know?

Comment: @Mary upload it somewhere and put the URL here in a comment. We can take it from there.

Comment: can you give me an example of where I might upload it?  I'm still pretty new at this, so I don't quit understand what you're asking of me.

Comment: @Mary Any storage site will do. Photobucket?

Comment: I have a skydrive with Microsoft!